# How to properly render JSON metadata into HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, json

Currently I am using the following code to extract data from a LD+JSON script at the header of any given page from my webiste and later I print that data to specific sections. So far so good.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = $(".metadata").html();
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    $('.title').html(json.name);
    $('.datePublished').html(json.datePublished);
    $('.dateModified').html(json.dateModified);
    $('.keywords').html(json.keywords);
    $('.author').html(json["author"]["name"]);
    $('.editor').html(json["editor"]["name"]);
    $('.publisher').html(json["publisher"]["name"]);
});
```

I then retrieve it this way:

```
<div class="article-meta">
<p>Author: <span class="author"></span>; Editor: <span class="editor"></span>; Publisher: <span class="publisher"></span>.</p>
<p><span class="article-small">Keywords: <span class="keywords"></span></span></p>
</div>
```

However, this is where something that I don't understand happens. If my page calls all of those parameters, it works just fine. But if there is, for example, no stated "editor", then all of the parameters below it don't print anymore. In the example above, "publisher" stops showing up because I am not calling "editor".

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the property json["author"] is undefined, Javascript will halt and not proceed when trying to read "name" subproperty (it can be checked within the browser console);

As a way to prevent this error, you can check previously if the value exists, like below:

```
if (json["author"] != undefined) { $('.author').html(json["author"]["name"]); }
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for the elegant solution!